# Service does not run from BroadcastReceiver? - Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I am trying to get my service to run when there is an outgoing call on my phone. But for some reason my service does not run when this happens. I know the code for the "CallReceiver" executes since I used a toast message to display if that runs. I am able to run the service through my main activity, but this means it will run regardless of whether an outgoing call is made....

Below is my code:

**The Receiver:**

```
package com.example.hiworld;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, CallService.class));

        Toast.makeText(context, "Call Receiver started",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d("Calling Someone", "onReceived");

    }


}
```

**The Service:**

```
package com.example.hiworld;


import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CallService extends IntentService  {

    public long StartTime=0;
    public long EndTime =0; 
    public long TotalTime = 0; 
    public long NumFreeMins = 0;


    public CallService() {
          super("CallService");
      }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


        StartTime = (System.currentTimeMillis())/60;

        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);




            if(tm.getCallState()==0) //getting the time whenever the phone is off 
            {

                EndTime = (System.currentTimeMillis())/60;
                TotalTime = EndTime-StartTime;
                 NumFreeMins = 300-TotalTime; 

                 //notify user
                 this.displaymsg();

            }   



    }

public void displaymsg()
{
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+NumFreeMins, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
}
```

I have seen some people use the line:

```
context.startService(new Intent(this, CallService.class));
```

instead of:

```
context.startService(new Intent(context, CallService.class));
```

but the latter does not work for me...

Comment: Show your logs just to know if something is wrong when you start the service. I would point your problem as something missing at the manifest related with the <service> tag.

Comment: check this tutorial will help you [Start Service from Broadcast Receiver ] (http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/03/start-service-from-broadcast-receiver.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying an `<intent-filter>` for your `IntentService` in the manifest for a specific 'action'. Example...

```
<service
    android:name=".CallService" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.hiworld.intent.DO_SOMETHING" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Then in the `onReceive(...)` method of your `BroadcastReceiver` do something like the following...

```
Intent callReceiverIntent = new Intent("com.example.hiworld.intent.DO_SOMETHING");

// Put the Intent received by the BroadcastReceiver as extras so the
// IntentService can process it...
callReceiverIntent.putExtras(intent);

context.startService(callReceiverIntent);
```

**EDIT:**

I built a simple test app based on the code you posted to pasrebin. I kept the code identical for the manifest, receiver and service and simply had to add a default `Activity` in order to get it to run.

I can see from monitoring logcat in the DDMS perspective of eclipse that the `CallReceiver` successfully receives the `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` `Intent` and does, in fact, start the `CallService`.

The problem is, however, with attempting to show a `Toast` from an `IntentService` which causes an exception due to a 'leaked handler' and silently crashes.

The reason behind this is that an `IntentService` uses a background thread to carry out its work and trying to show the `Toast` (i.e., a UI element) from a non-UI thread won't work as the app has no UI components running. So, regardless of whether you use the local `context` variable or `getApplicationContext()`, there simply is no UI context with which to associate the `Toast`.

The reason why it works when starting the `CallService` from an `Activity` is obviously because the `Activity` provides a UI context that can be used by the `Toast`. In short, it generally seems that attempting to use `Toast` from an `IntentService` isn't a good idea unless the `IntentService` is *always* started by a UI component and even then, having a background thread create UI elements (such as a `Toast`) may cause problems.

The only way that this can be made to work with the current model is to change the `IntentService` to a `Service`. By default, code execution of a `Service` is done on the main (UI) thread and it is quite legal for a `Service` to show a `Toast` regardless of whether there are any of the app's `Activities` showing or not. In fact, I modified the code to use a `Service` and placed the code from `onHandleIntent` in `onStartCommand()` and I can see the `Toasts` when making an outgoing call.

Comment: Hmm...I have already added that to my manifest file:

http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/iyI2uUcKBz

But not sure how to do the rest of what you said...is it wrong the way I have done it?

Comment: You've added an `<intent-filter>` section to your `<receiver>` element in the manifest which listens for `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`. What I'm suggesting is using your own custom Intent action `DO_SOMETHING` and add an `<intent-filter>` to your `<service>` element to 'listen' for it. You then start the `IntentService` using the `DO_SOMETHING` action.

Comment: Nope...still nothing.

The new manifest file, Receiver and service code is here: http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/AQInRptOhN

Cant figure out what I'm doing wrong :(

Comment: @user1508897 : Hmm, I can't see anything obvious I'm afraid. The method I showed in my answer is exactly how I start an `IntentService` from a `BroadcastReceiver` so it should work. I've downloaded your source code and will try it out but it won't be until later tonight. If I come up with anything I'll let you know.

Comment: @user1508897 : I don't know why I didn't spot it. The `IntentService` IS being started but attempting to show `Toast` messages from it is causing an exception and basically crashing it silently. You'll need to create `Notifications` if you want to inform the user as `Toast` from an `IntentService` isn't going to play nice.

Comment: @Squonk would the Toast work if he attached the Application Context? I'm pretty sure I've seen `Service`s and `Broadcast Recievers` `Toast` data before...

Comment: Hmm.. I can get the toast message from the service to work when I start it using my activity. I get it to say "Service started" , although I cant actually see it when I check whats running on my phone...

I also tried just commenting out all the toast code in the service and try it then, but it doesn't start anyway.. 

Just can't figure out why it's not starting using my Receiver :/

Comment: @user1508897 : See the edit at the end of my answer above for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
context.startService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), CallService.class));
```

Comment: Hmm, still can't get it to work. I tried that now, but I still get nothing. I even put a toast message whenever the service is called, and that never comes up...

Comment: @SalilPandit : See the edit at the end of my answer with respect to `Toast` and `IntentService`